# Table not rendering data properly using new contribution grouping feature

Tags: pdf

Using civicrm 4.6.7
I noticed the new grouping feature when making thank you letters for contribution. It seems like an amazing feature to agregate all the contacts donations into 1 pdf rather than having to create multiple letters. 
The problem is the way the PDF is rendered.

Civicrm adds a new column for each piece of data which makes it unusable.

I would like it to create a new row for each new line of data. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a link to an equivalent on the Demo site - thanks

Comment: The link wont work but if you go to the demo site Contributions>find contributions
sort data by name and select multiple donations for the same name. Then click Actions>Make contributions thank you letters.
Select 
grouping = Contacts
Separator = Table cell
then create a table in the editor with tokens : contribution amount and receive date and create pdf

Comment: I didn't quite replicate what you had. i ended up with comma separated even when selecting Table Cell as separator. Can you screenshot your template? BTW did you try the table as a single column with Date, then underneath Amount?

Comment: Interesting it does the same for me now as well. It separates the data with a comma.