# Year End Contribution Summary for Donors

Tags: civicontribute, receipts

I'd like to send out to all my donors a summary of all their contributions in the past year.

CiviCRM seems to have a feature that should do that by grouping the contributions per contact when printing out thank you letters but that feature is broken as illustrated here : [Table not rendering data properly using new contribution grouping feature](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/5067/table-not-rendering-data-properly-using-new-contribution-grouping-feature)

Any work arounds that I am not thinking of?
Thanks

Comment: Just added the correct link. Had put the wrong link in the original post

Answer (score 1):

The extension Summary Fields, will give you a token for total contributions per year, which you can use

Answer (score 1):

In case you are looking for a formal contribution receipt you may want to have a look at those two extensions for contribution receipts:

[1. Donation Receipts](https://civicrm.org/extensions/donation-receipts)

[2. CDN Tax Receipts](https://civicrm.org/extensions/cdn-tax-receipts)

Answer (score 0):

SO I ended up solving this by using Drupal Views.
I created a list of all the donors who have completed donations in 2015 and linking each name to another page which is also view (table) that lists all the 2015 contributions with a header which includes the letter.

I then formatted the page for printing with css.

The only downside is that I have to print them one by one but it works.